# Python3 sorting lists of nested dicts with lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda, hash

I have a deep nested object of various lists and dicts that I retrieve as json which I need to compare to another version of itself. The issue is that all lists are basically unsorted, therefore I need to sort before comparing them. Any deep diff library I've tried failed without proper sorting the dicts position in the lists, so here we go.

Sample object that requires sorting:

```
{
    "main":{
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2",
        "key3":[{
            "sub1":"value2",
            "sub2":{
                "subsub":[{
                    "subsubsub1":10,
                    "subsubsub2":11,
                    "subsubsub3":[10,11,12]
                },{
                    "subsubsub1":7,
                    "subsubsub2":8,
                    "subsubsub3":[9,7,8]
                }]
            }
        },{
            "sub1":"value1",
            "sub2":{
                "subsub":[{
                    "subsubsub1":1,
                    "subsubsub2":2,
                    "subsubsub3":[1,2,3]
                },
                {
                    "subsubsub1":4,
                    "subsubsub2":5,
                    "subsubsub3":[5,6,4]
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Besides a few recursive loops I'm trying to sort the dicts by translating them with sorted lists into sorted tuples and hash them.

***Edit:***
The object is passed into unnest()

```
    def unnest(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d.update({k: unnest(v)})
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            d.update({k: unsort(v)})
    return d


def unsort(l):
    for i, e in enumerate(l):
        if isinstance(e, dict):
            l[i] = unnest(e)
        elif isinstance(e, list):
            l[i] = unsort(e)
    return sorted(l, key=lambda i: sort_hash(i))


def unnest_hash(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d.update({k: unnest_hash(v)})
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            d.update({k: sort_hash(v)})
    return hash(tuple(sorted(d.items())))


def sort_hash(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        for i, e in enumerate(l):
            if isinstance(e, dict):
                l[i] = unnest_hash(e)
            elif isinstance(e, list):
                l[i] = sort_hash(e)
        return hash(tuple(sorted(l)))
    elif isinstance(l, dict):
        return unnest_hash(l)
    else:
        return hash(l)
```

However for some reason the hash value gets written into the "sorted" list:

```
{'main': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': [{'sub1': 'value2', 'sub2': -4046234112924644199}, {'sub1': 'value1', 'sub2': 4015568797712784641}]}}
```

How can I prevent the sort value in the lambda function to be written into the returned sorted list?
Thanks!

Comment: quite difficult to debug if you haven't provided `sort_hash` code

Comment: Added all 4 functions that are taking part in the sorting to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sort_hash` function is mutating the value passed into it. That's why you see it in the original values are the sort:

```
l[i] = unnest_hash(e)
```

and

```
 l[i] = sort_hash(e)
```

both modify the value you are trying to hash. `unnest_hash` also modifies the original values:

```
d.update({k: unnest_hash(v)})
```

A hash calculation for sorting must never modify the value it is hashing.